# Angular translate vs ng-i18next

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have used angular ng-i18next plugin for i18n feature that really good plugin but recently I saw someone use the plugin angular-translate and that have big star in the github repository.

The question for who use both plugin before can give the advance and disavance between 2 plugin.

Reference link:

[Angular translate](https://github.com/angular-translate)

[ng-i18next](https://github.com/i18next/ng-i18next)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with i18next but angular-translate was adapted by angular team as official module. 
so I recommend you to use angular-translate.

Angular-translate is really easy to use and have well documentation:

https://angular-translate.github.io

from angular translate official site:

**What?**
angular-translate is an AngularJS module that makes your life much easier when it comes to i18n and l10n including lazy loading and pluralization.

**Features:**
It provides components like filters and directives, asynchronous loading of i18n data, full pluralization support through MessageFormat and much more!

**Flexibility:**
angular-translate is very flexible. You can build your own loaders, storages or error handlers and extend angular-translate to your needs!